# finding strings in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I need to write a code that will return all the string found in a list, but I do not know if there is a function for that. 
the code should return something like this:

```
>>>findStrings([3,'Good',['henry',7], " ", False, "Morning!", 9])
"Good Morning"
```

So far i have this

```
def findStrings(a):
if (type(a[0])==str):
    return(a[0])
if type(a[1])==str:
    return(a[1])
if type(a[2])==str:
    return(l[2])
```

and this works, but I don't know how long the list will be so I would basically have to do this for every item in the list, and that wouldn't make a lot of sense. Is there another way to do this?
can I make come kind of loop maybe?

Thank you

Comment: Should the example result include `'henry'`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 From his example, he doesn't include it in his desired output.

Comment: Ah, true. Now how about the extra space and the absent `!` in that output?

Comment: Ahh. I don't know. :/ Typo in his output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would want to make a loop. You might do something like:

```
def findStrings(a):
    return [x for x in a if isinstance(x, str)]
```

This uses a *list comprehension* to return all of the string instances in one go. This returns a list, so you could print the results with:

```
for x in findStrings(a):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, just go through each element using a `for` loop. This would be simple using `isinstance`:

```
def find_strings(l):
    strings = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            strings.append(i)
    return strings # returns ['Good', 'Morning!']
```

If you want to concatenate (Make a string instead of a list) in the end:

```
def find_strings(l):
    strings = ""
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            strings += i
    return strings # returns "Good Morning!"
```